# priority of the executed javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Say I use google map api via two sites

```
<head>
 <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&hl=zh-CN&v=3.21&callback=initMap" async defer>
 </script>
 <script 
    src="http://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false&hl=zh-CN&v=3.21&callback=initMap" async defer>
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
    function initMap() {
      //something
    }
 </script>
</body>
```

Sometimes I can't connect to the first site, but the code still works. Now I want to use the first site whenever I can connect to it. Is there a way to set the priority of the two sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the first with javascript using `document.createElement` and add an `onerror` event handler that sets the `src` to the second source if the first fails:

```
 <script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false&hl=zh-CN&v=3.21&callback=initMap';
    script.onerror = function() {
        // if the above source fails to load, try this one
        this.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&hl=zh-CN&v=3.21&callback=initMap';
        this.onerror = function() {
            console.log('Nothing loaded!');
        }
    }
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but the function script.onerror=... don't work.

Comment: Is it different to put the script in head vs body?

Comment: Creating another element in the function works. Why?